# Proper SQL query command with SQL Compact is failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I've got a function that stores temporary information generated for every user authenticated in the system. This 'session ID' is a string stored in a Sessions table, along the original ID of the user which authenticated and was given said session identifier.

The function to remove/deauthenticate/invalidate an existing session first checks if the user exists through another method implemented as follows:

```
        int userId = 0;
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        SqlCeParameterCollection sqlParams = cmd.Parameters;
        sqlParams.AddWithValue("@User", userName);
        cmd.Connection = this.conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE (Username = @User)";

        userId = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        cmd.Dispose();
```

Afterwards it tries to find an existing session for that user, which is to be removed (via a different method again):

```
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        SqlCeParameterCollection sqlParams = cmd.Parameters;
        sqlParams.AddWithValue("@SID", mysession);
        sqlParams.AddWithValue("@UID", myuserid);

        cmd.Connection = this.Connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM UserSessions WHERE (SessionID = @SID) AND (User_Id = @UID)";
        int foo = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

...which fails. No exception is raised unfortunately. So I added an **insecure** equivalent using a non parametrized query string:

```
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT Id FROM UserSessions WHERE (SessionID = '{0}') AND (User_Id = {1})", mysession, myuserid);
        cmd.Prepare();
        int bar = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Added a breakpoint, paused, copy pasted the query into the Visual Studio Query tool and voila, it indeed **worked**. But after continuing, that **query in the code failed as well**. I'm unable to find the culprit of this annoying issue since **no exception is raised** and everything seems correct. The data exists, the parameters are provided in proper types (string and int) and I'm out of things to check. The connection is open and so forth.

Any clues from anyone around? Thanks!

**Update**: Mea culpa, missed the fact that the **function used ExecuteScalar until I modified it** for testing. It **does** use ExecuteScalar and **returns null**, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
int foo = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

... but you're clearly trying to execute a query (a SELECT)! Use `ExecuteScalar` again, as you did in the first code, or `ExecuteReader` and look through the results appropriately. If you stick with `ExecuteScalar`, you should first check whether the result is `null` to indicate no results.

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) returns the number of rows affected by an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE command - which is what it's intended for. I suspect it's returning -1 for you, as documented:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy response, my bad. Somehow the error went away. I think it might have had something to do with synchronicity but it was weird as hell.

Comment: @soze: If you're still using ExecuteNonQuery then the code is still broken, and you should still fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use set [] to avoid ambiguity with database keyword.

```
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Id] FROM [Users] WHERE ([Username] = @User)";
```

and use `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecureReader()` method when working with SELECT statements.